# How to declare an array of JComboBox in Java

Tags: arrays, jcombobox

I need to use an array of ComboBox, I try to declare in different way, but I can't.

Can someone help me?

Last way is:

```
final String[] comString = {"aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee" };
private JComboBox<String> comList[]= new JComboBox[10];
```

Answer (score 0):

With this declaration it works:

```
private JComboBox comList[]={null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null};
```